# How to do some modifications in geom_boxplot?

Tags: r, boxplot

I want to do some modifications of a geom_boxplot:

1. reverse the order of the Y axis (A1 in top and A4 in bottom).
2. Is it possible to plot my legend on the graph, not beside the graph.

Here is an example:

```
aa <- c(rep("A1",5), rep("A2",3), rep("A3",4), rep("A4",9))
aa <- as.factor(aa)
per <- runif(length(aa), min=0, max=100)
per <- trunc(per)
z <- data.frame(x=aa,y=per) 
z$ch <- NA
z[z$x %in% c("A1","A2"), "ch"] <- "string1"
z[z$x %in% c("A3"), "ch"] <- "string2"
z[z$x %in% c("A4"), "ch"] <- "string3"

z$ch <- as.factor(z$ch)

p <- ggplot(z, aes(x, y, fill = ch)) + 
geom_boxplot(size = 0.2, position = "dodge", outlier.colour = "red", outlier.shape = 16,     outlier.size = 2) + 
geom_jitter(size=1) + opts(legend.position = "right") + 
scale_colour_hue("variable") +
coord_flip()
print(p)
```

Comment: I expanded my answer to also include placing the legend inside the plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reversing the order of the labels on the y-axis can be done by reordering the levels of the factor (z$x):

```
z$x = with(z, factor(x, rev(levels(x))))
```

To get the legend inside the plot you can use the `legend.position` option. The trick is that when you set it to e.g. "top" or "bottom" the legend is placed outside the plot. When using a vector of two numbers, it places the legend at that position inside the plot. In code:

```
p + opts(legend.position = c(0.85,0.85), 
         legend.background = theme_rect("white"))
```

Which leads to the following plot, which I think is what you wanted:

[image]

Note the addition of legend.background to draw a filled rectangle surrounding the legend. Furthermore, I myself do not really like having the legend inside the plot as it can obscure the data. But that is, ofcourse, for you to decide :).

Comment: And thank you for providing some example code, this always helps greatly in answering questions.